# How to make this so it won't take minutes to load on my html page

Tags: sql

I want to make this again so if i load a page it won't load again the next time, because this way takes sometimes minutes to load. (There are around 14k items in the database categories)

function Hoofdcategorie() {

```
global $conn;

$query = "SELECT Name, ID
FROM Categorieen
Where Parent = -1";

$sql = $conn->prepare($query);
$sql->execute();

$hoofdrubrieken = '';

while($rij = $sql->fetch()){
    $name = $rij['Name'];
    $takeId = $rij['ID'];
    $id = 'text' . $takeId;
    $labelID = $id . 1234567890;
    $flushID = 'flusID' . $id;
    $buttonName = 'loadbutton' . $id;
    $hoofdrubrieken .= <<<EOD
    <div class="accordion-item buttonColor">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id='$labelID'>
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target='#$id' 
            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls='$id' id="$buttonName"  style="background-color:#cc99ff;">
                $name
            </button>
        </h2>
        <div id='$id' class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby='$labelID' data-bs-parent="#flushID">

    EOD;
    
    $hoofdrubrieken .= "<div class='accordion-body'>";
    $hoofdrubrieken .= "<div class='accordion accordion-flush' id = '$flushID'>";
    $hoofdrubrieken .= Subcategoriefirst($takeId, $flushID);
    $hoofdrubrieken .= '</div></div></div></div>';
}

return $hoofdrubrieken;
```

}

Comment: 14k rows is nothing - it should take milliseconds :/

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a SQL issue, it is a coding issue - so you'd be better off tagging your question with a more relevant tag. However, your code seems to be looping through the SQL resultset and adding a button to your form/output for each record in the resultset. If you say there are 14k records then you're adding 14k buttons - which makes no sense (to me)